# React - create dynamic list of child components with onClick

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, components

Note: Using ES 2015.

I am creating a filtering tool. When the component loads, a single row of filtering options is mounted, along with a button to add additional rows.

```
addAnotherFilter() {
  return (
    <FilterRow 
      filterData={this.state.newFilter} 
      filterId={this.state.filterIdCounter} 
      handleFilterIdCounter={this.handleFilterIdCounter} 
      updateValue={this.updateValue} 
      updateType={this.updateType} 
      updateOperator={this.updateOperator} 
    />
  )
} 

render(){
  <return (
    <div>
      <div className="filters-container">
        <FilterRow 
          filterData={this.state.newFilter} 
          filterId={this.state.filterIdCounter} 
          handleFilterIdCounter={this.handleFilterIdCounter} 
          updateValue={this.updateValue} 
          updateType={this.updateType} 
          updateOperator={this.updateOperator} 
        />
      </div>
      <button onClick={this.addAnotherFilter}>Add another</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

How can I have the new filterRows append to the end of the filters-container div? I get a lot of data back from the filterRow with selected options, and I need to store the selected options per row in objects in an array.

I also need to be able to delete each row and remove its data from the array.

Comment: I assume by `self` you mean `this`?

Comment: yes sorry, I typically define that somewhere. I'll add it in.

Comment: that is an antipattern. You should never have to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to update the `state` in order to re-render the UI. To update the state, you have to use `this.setState()`. Forget a bit about "appending" stuff in React since it will be very rare. In the [React way](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) your UI will reflect the changes in your state. Your code should look like this:

```
...

state = {
  filterRows: [
    { 
      filterData: "name", // initial filterData value
      filterId: 0 // initial filterId Value
    }
  ]
}

addAnotherFilter(filterData, filterId) {
  this.setState({
    filterRows: [...this.state.filterRows, {filterData, filterId}];
  })
} 

removeFilter(index) {
  this.setState({
    filterRows: [...state.slice(0, index), ...state.slice(index + 1)];
  })
} 

render() {
  <return (
     <div>
       <div className="filters-container">
          {this.state.filterRows.map((row, i) =>
            <FilterRow
              key={i}
              filterData={row.filterData}
              filterId={row.filterId}
              handleFilterIdCounter={this.handleFilterIdCounter}
              updateValue={this.updateValue}
              updateType={this.updateType}
              updateOperator={this.updateOperator}
              removeFilter={() => this.removeFilter(i)}
            />
          )}
       </div>
       <button onClick={() => this.addAnotherFilter("profession", this.state.filterRows.length)}>Add another</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is the format you have in the methods compatible with ES '15? Or could you tell me how to do the same in ES '15? Also, each new row will use the same default template with empty values. Each row has two select boxes and an input field, and by adding an additional filterRow the user can stack filters.

Comment: It works on ES2015 :). "Also, each new row will use the same default template with empty values. Each row has two select boxes and an input field, and by adding an additional filterRow the user can stack filters", cool, my code creates it for a simple example, you can go ahead and adapt it for your needs. Just try a bit.